# How do I add audio to a single animated action in Blender?

Tags: animation, audio, actions

I have animated an action using the action editor, but I want audio to play during that specific action. I could not find any useful tutorials explaining this online, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

To add audio to the animation you can use the sequence editor, in the N panel you can activate the sound waves for a better visualization.
[image]

You can also enable audio scrubbing and audio sync to hear the audio along with the animation.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, whenever I switch to a different action, the audio still plays. Can I assign the audio to only play during that certain action?

Comment: You can't assign an audio to an action, but you can add each audio in a channel and rename the channels, and when you change action you just disable all channels except the current action. [Screenshoot](https://imgur.com/a/JXqWlF2)